# Elasticsearch regular expression in Kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new here, using Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana.

Right now I have some logs in Kibana, with fields like "timestamp" "message". (They are shown in the down-left corner of Kibana.)
But the "message" contains lots of information, like:

> ID: 100 | Name: Justin

How can I break down this into fields? And I want to do a **regular expression** to take out the "Justin".
Where should I change? In which file?

Comment: Check logstash examples, obtaining fields from your message is what logstash is used for. Some defaults for apache logging for instance are available.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is logstash's [grok{} feature](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/grok).  It allows you to define/use patterns against the input to create fields that would be stored in elasticsearch.

Here's an [intro article](http://svops.com/blog/introduction-to-logstash-grok-patterns/) that might help.